# How to read Arabic text from PDF using Python script

Tags: python, pdf, utf-8, character-encoding, arabic

I have a code written in Python that reads from PDF files and convert it to text file.

The problem occurred when I tried to read **Arabic text** from PDF files. I know that the error is in the **coding and encoding process** but I don't know how to fix it.

The system converts Arabic PDF files but the text file is empty.
and display this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\test\Downloads\pdf-txt\text maker.py", line 68, in 
>       f.write(content) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa9' in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)

Code:

```
import os
from os import chdir, getcwd, listdir, path
import codecs
import pyPdf
from time import strftime

def check_path(prompt):
    ''' (str) -> str
    Verifies if the provided absolute path does exist.
    '''
    abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    while path.exists(abs_path) != True:
        print "\nThe specified path does not exist.\n"
        abs_path = raw_input(prompt)
    return abs_path    

print "\n"

folder = check_path("Provide absolute path for the folder: ")

list=[]
directory=folder
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.pdf'):
            t=os.path.join(directory,filename)

            list.append(t)

m=len(list)
print (m)
i=0
while i<=m-1:

    path=list[i]
    print(path)
    head,tail=os.path.split(path)
    var="\\"

    tail=tail.replace(".pdf",".txt")
    name=head+var+tail

    content = ""
    # Load PDF into pyPDF
    pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(file(path, "rb"))
            # Iterate pages
    for j in range(0, pdf.getNumPages()):
        # Extract text from page and add to content
        content += pdf.getPage(j).extractText() + "\n"
    print strftime("%H:%M:%S"), " pdf  -> txt "
    f=open(name,'w')
    content.encode('utf-8')
    f.write(content)
    f.close
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Is there an exception or does the script exit silently? Does it work as expected for PDFs that contain only text written with Latin script?

Comment: @lenz THE SCRIPT work as expected with no  error on non ARABIC content    but when it comes to ARABIC it convert PDF to empty text file

Comment: Oh I see. You have to write `content = content.encode('utf-8')` on line 68. String methods never modify strings in-place, you always have to capture the return value.

Comment: Rany, did this work? Because once you fixed your code, I suggest you delete this post, since it's very unlikely to help future readers. Your problem turned out to have nothing to do with encoding, Arabic, or PDF – it's simply a bug that shows up when the content contains non-ASCII characters.

Comment: @lenz the error is gone but still the converted file is empty

Comment: did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of problems:

1. `content.encode('utf-8')` doesn't do anything.  The return value is the encoded content, but you have to assign it to a variable.  Better yet, open the file with an encoding, and write Unicode strings to that file.  `content` appears to be Unicode data.

Example (works for both Python 2 and 3):

```
 import io
 f = io.open(name,'w',encoding='utf8')
 f.write(content)
```

2. If you don't close the file properly, you may see no content because the file is not flushed to disk.  You have `f.close` not `f.close()`.  It's better to use `with`, which ensures the file is closed when the block exits.

Example:

```
import io
with io.open(name,'w',encoding='utf8') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

In Python 3, you don't need to import and use `io.open` but it still works.  `open` is equivalent.  Python 2 needs the `io.open` form.

Comment: I USED your answer to fix my code.
now it convert the arabic PDF text  INTO TXT FILE BUT WITH  **unreadable characters**.

Comment: @RanyFahed What software do you use to inspect the text file? The viewer/editor might be using the wrong encoding.

Comment: @RanyFahed Also since it looks like you are on Windows, many Windows programs assume a localized encoding such as Windows-1252 on U.S. Windows.  You can use `utf-8-sig` to write a byte order mark (BOM) signature and some programs recognize this to know to use UTF-8.

Comment: @lenz for PDF files i am using **PDF Complete**
           for TXT files  i am using  **NotePad ++**

Comment: @MarkTolonen i did not understand your comment

Comment: @RanyFahed Use `with io.open(name, 'w', encoding='utf-8-sig')` and see if Notepad++ is able to display the text properly.

Answer (score 0):

you can use anthor library called pdfplumber instead of using pypdf or PyPDF2

```
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display
with pdfplumber.open(r'example.pdf') as pdf:
    my_page = pdf.pages[10]
    thepages=my_page.extract_text()
    reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape(thepages)
    bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
    print(bidi_text)
```